# SQL Select not grouping properly

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Another newbie question here,

I have the following Select:

```
SELECT    
    DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, CIC.StatusDateTime)) AS ST_Date,
    CIC.UserId,
    MIN(CIC.StatusDateTime) as Beginning,
    MAX(CIC.EndDateTime) as ending,
    DATEPART(hour,MAX(CIC.EndDateTime) - MIN(CIC.StatusDateTime)) * 3600 
     + DATEPART(minute, MAX(CIC.EndDateTime) - MIN(CIC.StatusDateTime)) * 60 
     + DATEPART(second,MAX(CIC.EndDateTime) - MIN(CIC.StatusDateTime)) AS Login_Time, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN RS.AGT_STATE_GRP = 5 THEN StateDuration ELSE 0 END) AS Lunch, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN RS.AGT_STATE_GRP = 3 THEN StateDuration ELSE 0 END) AS Break_, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN RS.AGT_STATE_GRP = 4 THEN StateDuration ELSE 0 END) AS Coaching, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN RS.AGT_STATE_GRP = 10 THEN StateDuration ELSE 0 END) AS SYS_Down, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN RS.AGT_STATE_GRP = 7 THEN StateDuration ELSE 0 END) AS Training, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN RS.AGT_STATE_GRP = 6 THEN StateDuration ELSE 0 END) AS Meeting, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN RS.AGT_STATE_GRP = 11 THEN StateDuration ELSE 0 END) AS Default_
FROM dbo.CIC_AgentActivityLog_TMP AS CIC
INNER JOIN dbo.REF_AGT_STATES AS RS 
ON CIC.StatusKey = RS.AGT_STATE_DESC
Where CIC.StatusDateTime >='2011-09-01'
GROUP BY CIC.StatusDateTime, CIC.UserId, CIC.EndDateTime
ORDER BY ST_Date,UserID,StatusDateTime;
```

Using this, my results do not seem to be grouping at all. What I am trying to have is a single row with date,userid,firstlogin,lastlogin,totallogintime,and then a bunch of codes with their duration in seconds. I have something very similar for another data source which works fine.

I have tried converting and using cast with the first date thinking the 00:00:00 at the end might be conflicting, but to no avail. I am unsure what more info you guys might need, just let me know.

*Edit1 - My MIN(CIC.StatusDateTime) as Beginning,MAX(CIC.EndDateTime) as ending seem to not be helping. For an agent, i have three rows that all have different start and end times. The min and max are not giving me the actual min and max for the whole day.

Here is the source Data:

```
userID  StatusDateTime  StatusKey   EndDateTime StateDuration
bBarsby 9/1/2011 11:36  Out of the office   9/1/2011 11:36  0
bBarsby 9/1/2011 11:36  Out of the office   9/1/2011 11:36  5
bBarsby 9/1/2011 11:36  Available   9/1/2011 14:18  9711
bBarsby 9/1/2011 14:18  Away from desk  9/1/2011 14:39  1261
bBarsby 9/1/2011 14:39  Available   9/1/2011 19:51  18693
bBarsby 9/1/2011 19:51  Out of the office   9/1/2011 19:51  4
bBarsby 9/1/2011 19:51  Out of the office   9/1/2011 19:51  0
```

Here is the results

```
ST_Date UserID  Beginning   Ending  LoginTime   Lunch   Break   Coaching      Etc.
9/1/2011 0:00   bBarsby 9/1/2011 11:36  9/1/2011 14:18  9711    0   0   0   0
9/1/2011 0:00   bBarsby 9/1/2011 14:18  9/1/2011 14:39  1261    0   0   0   0
9/1/2011 0:00   bBarsby 9/1/2011 14:39  9/1/2011 19:51  18693   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Also you are ordering by StatusDateTime, but that column is not in the select list.

Comment: Removed it, still have the same result.

Comment: Can you provide a handful of sample data and desired results? Of course, if you're grouping by `UserID`, the `MIN` and `MAX` operators have no idea you want to stay within a single day. Maybe your WHERE clause should also say `< '20110902'`?

Comment: Getting the data now, posting asap.

Comment: Can you clarify, those are the results you're *getting*, or those are the results you *want*?

Comment: That's what he's getting.  See the unique endings?

Comment: David B's solution seems to have worked. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaron Bertrand has the right idea.  You absolutely should not define groups by the enddate.

Here's the query re-written with that group by.

```
SELECT
  sub.ST_Date,
  sub.UserId,
  MIN(sub.StatusDateTime) as Beginning,
  MAX(sub.EndDateTime) as ending,
  DATEPART(hour,MAX(sub.EndDateTime) - MIN(sub.StatusDateTime)) * 3600
  + DATEPART(minute, MAX(sub.EndDateTime) - MIN(sub.StatusDateTime)) * 60
  + DATEPART(second,MAX(sub.EndDateTime) - MIN(sub.StatusDateTime)) AS Login_Time,
  SUM(CASE WHEN sub.AGT_STATE_GRP = 5 THEN StateDuration ELSE 0 END) AS Lunch,
  SUM(CASE WHEN sub.AGT_STATE_GRP = 3 THEN StateDuration ELSE 0 END) AS Break_,
  SUM(CASE WHEN sub.AGT_STATE_GRP = 4 THEN StateDuration ELSE 0 END) AS Coaching,
  SUM(CASE WHEN sub.AGT_STATE_GRP = 10 THEN StateDuration ELSE 0 END) AS SYS_Down,
  SUM(CASE WHEN sub.AGT_STATE_GRP = 7 THEN StateDuration ELSE 0 END) AS Training,
  SUM(CASE WHEN sub.AGT_STATE_GRP = 6 THEN StateDuration ELSE 0 END) AS Meeting,
  SUM(CASE WHEN sub.AGT_STATE_GRP = 11 THEN StateDuration ELSE 0 END) AS Default_
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, CIC.StatusDateTime)) AS ST_Date
    CIC.UserId,
    CIC.StatusDateTime,
    CIC.EndDateTime,
    RS.AGT_STATE_GRP,
    StateDuration
  FROM
    dbo.CIC_AgentActivityLog_TMP AS CIC
    JOIN dbo.REF_AGT_STATES AS RS
    ON CIC.StatusKey = RS.AGT_STATE_DESC
  WHERE CIC.StatusDateTime >='2011-09-01'
) sub
GROUP BY sub.ST_Date, sub.UserId
ORDER BY sub.ST_Date, sub.UserId
```

Comment: I don't normal "gimme the code" over a correct answer (Aaron's), but Grouping by a derived column is somewhat of a pain in sql (SELECT is run logically after GROUP BY).

Answer (score 4):

You're grouping by `CIC.StatusDateTime` and `CIC.EndDateTime` ... try just:

```
GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, CIC.StatusDateTime)), CIC.UserId
```

Comment: I still have the same results. I edited my OP, I left out some crucial info.

Comment: By "the same results" do you mean that you have multiple rows per user still, or just that the MIN/MAX fall outside of the day you're interested in, or both, or neither? Again, please see my comment - provide some sample data and desired results, it's much easier than reverse engineering word problems.

Comment: I posted some data. The desired results are one row per agent per day.

Answer (score 0):

use ST_Date in group by as this is the column name in your table.

```
GROUP BY CIC.StatusDateTime, CIC.UserId, CIC.EndDateTime
to
GROUP BY CIC.ST_DATE, CIC.UserId, CIC.EndDateTime
```

Edit:

```
group by DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, CIC.StatusDateTime)),CIC.UserId, MAX(CIC.EndDateTime)
```

Comment: You can't group by `ST_Date` - this column is not in the table, it's just the alias of an expression in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: You also can't `GROUP BY ... MAX()`. I'm not trying to pick nits, but have you tested anything you've suggested?